# RMS and average value of a DC signal - Which is the correct way to eliminate the inaccuracies due to incorrect measurement setup?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope, measurement, voltage-measurement, rms

I have a 5V DC signal and there are some ripples on top of the DC signal in the range of 50-100mV (maybe due my measurement inaccuracies or the switching noise coupling from other sources.)

In that case, to properly capture the accurate value of the DC signal without the AC noise ripple, should I use the RMS value of the scope measurement to capture it or the mean (average) value of the scope measurement to capture it?

My objective is to avoid the ripple due my the switching noise which couples, kind of like common mode noise. Which is the correct thing to do? And please explain why?

Comment: The DC bias is included in the RMS value you get. If you want to focus only on the ripple, then you just want to measure that alone. Use AC coupling on the scope, would be one suggestion to try. But then, I'm not entirely sure what you want from reading you, either. (You have other questions, as well. Not sure what the focus is.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just want to understand that whether the RMS value measurement of a DC Signal would also include the Low noise ripple present on top of the DC Signal due to various reasons?

Comment: The problem is that the DC component can dominate the RMS output. For example, suppose you have a \$5\:\text{V}\$ DC bias and \$3\:\text{V}_\text{PEAK}\$ ripple, then you will get \$\approx 5.43\:\text{V}_\text{RMS}\$. Note which dominates here? If you AC couple the input, the DC drops out and you'd get \$\approx 2.12\:\text{V}_\text{RMS}\$, which actually reflects the ripple issue.

Comment: Ok. So avoid the ripple issue, I must choose the RMS measurement value instead of mean value, right? But Why can't I choose the mean measurement value instead of the RMS to avoid the ripple effect altogether?

Comment: Suppose you average the signal I mentioned earlier? It would average \$5\:\text{V}\$. You would not see any effect of ripple, regardless of how large it may be. That's because the ripple itself averages to zero. (Technically, this depends upon the ripple shape itself. But if it is a sine, what I said is true.) So RMS helps you if you are looking for a useful measure of magnitude where smaller is better and larger is worse.

Comment: Please don't blindly trust numbers displayed on your 'scope (Jonk wants you to delve into the roots of RMS, MEAN). The # display often has too many digits of complex waveforms, calculated with too-simple algorithms. For example, a square wave with a nasty short sharp overshoot can display "Pk-Pk" far too high. Another: Do you know if RMS or AVG measures just what you see on the screen, or a far longer time scale? It makes a BIG difference!

Answer (score 1):

> *In that case, to properly capture the accurate value of the DC Signal
> without the AC Noise ripple, should I use the RMS value of the scope
> measurement to capture it or the Mean (average) value of the scope
> measurement to capture it?*

If you want to know how much power will be flowing in a resistor connected to that DC voltage (plus ripple), then you would use the RMS value displayed by the measurement equipment.

If you want to know the average level of the voltage use the mean level displayed by the measurement equipment.

It all depends on what you want to measure and that depends on why you want to measure it; RMS gives you the effective heating value of the voltage should it be connected to a resistor.

On the other hand, if you were designing an amplifier or a voltage regulator and, you wanted to inspect the "static" errors in the circuit, you'd measure the average level. If you wanted to measure output noise you'd AC couple and measure either the peak-to-peak or the RMS of AC coupled waveform.